# Is car manufacturing haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Let's say that I want to open up a car manufacturing company. Would it be haram as long as they are running on electric engines (like Tesla Motors) and the power outlets use renewable resources like Solar power or wind power?

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing resources is Halal. But if we misuse resources then it's haram.
So car manufacturing is halal if you are running it in a right way.

Comment: yes I do agree, example if you were camping and you used fire to warm your self its not harm, or you might die from cold. but if you use fire to burn a forest, then its haram. so car manufactoring not haram because you are helping people to transport quickly

Answer (score 1):

**Is car manufacturing haram?**

Manufacturing cars is not haram. Allah has permitted trade and thereby permitted manufacturing products. Allah says (what means):

> [2:275] Those who consume interest cannot stand [on the Day of
>   Resurrection] except as one stands who is being beaten by Satan into
>   insanity. That is because they say, "Trade is [just] like interest."
>   **But Allah has permitted trade** and has forbidden interest. So whoever
>   has received an admonition from his Lord and desists may have what is
>   past, and his affair rests with Allah. But whoever returns to [dealing
>   in interest or usury] - those are the companions of the Fire; they
>   will abide eternally therein.

---

> Let's say that I want to open up a car manufacturing company, would it
>   be haram as long as they are running on electric engines (like Tesla
>   Motors) and the power outlets use renewable resources like Solar power
>   or wind power?

That would be perfectly halal. However, your company should abide by the rules imposed by the authorities.

Answer (score -3):

Cars are haram reason one the pollution from a car is not clean reason two pollution from a car destroys the planet. Reason three factories which make all the parts of a cars destroy the planet . Now I'll ask one question did prophet Muhammad or any of his disciples drive cars and have factories which destroy the planet not only that the pollution from the cars are killing the planets immune system which is the ozone layer which is protecting the green algae which allows us to have abundance of oxygen as the main source of the planets oxygen is made from green algae I can explain further I think I've made my point here and if the car's keep on polluting and killing the ozone there there 1-day all the green algae would be gone and the fish will start to die because of two reasons one of the reasons is a green algae will no longer be able to survive the other reason is something will replace the green algae I cannot mention anymore